# spring integration sftp java dsl : cannot resolve method handleWithAdapter

Tags: spring-integration

I'm follow this  docs [this  docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/sftp.html#_configuring_with_the_java_dsl_21)

and add maven depency:

```
 <dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-integration-sftp</artifactId>
     <version>5.0.0.M6</version>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-integration-java-dsl</artifactId>
     <version>1.2.3.RELEASE</version>
 </dependency>
```

But it cannot resolve these method:
[image]

does I miss anything?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Starting with Spring Integration `5.0`, whole Java DSL project is merged to the core project. So, you don't need that extra `spring-integration-java-dsl` dependency anymore. More over it isn't compatible with Spring Integration `5.0`.

There is no any more such a `handleWithAdapter()` since there is no single entry point because all the namespace factories are distributed between appropriate modules.

So, right now you have to do this:

```
.handle(Sftp.outboundGateway(...))
```

See [Migration Guide](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/wiki/Spring-Integration-4.3-to-5.0-Migration-Guide) for more info.

And also follow back to the past from release [blog post](https://spring.io/blog/2017/09/14/spring-integration-5-0-milestone-7-and-4-3-12-available).